# Rspec - config.before(:suite) not running in spec_helper

Tags: rspec, configuration, automated-tests

I'm currently looking to set up a hash in memory that can be used across my entire suite
I am looking to do the following

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) { $user_tokens = initialize_my_stuff }
end
```

However, when I go to run my suite, I get an error from one of my specs with this error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

It's trying to run this:

```
$user_tokens.each do |user,token|
  describe 'foo bar' do
    ...
  end
end
```

If I comment out this spec, the `before(:suite)` runs as expected.

Is there a way I can ensure that the `before(:suite)` block runs *before* attempting to do anything with the specs?

Comment: Is `initialize_my_stuff` really that expensive? Can you just memorize it and use it in your specs `initialize_my_stuff.each ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what happens:

```
config.before(:suite) { $user_tokens = initialize_my_stuff }
```

It Will be run **before suite** (not surprisingly), but...

```
$user_tokens.each do |user,token|
  describe 'foo bar' do
    ...
  end
end
```

..is just the spec definition, happening **way before** actual suite execution.

In other words:

```
  describe 'foo bar' do
    ...
  end
```

is just a bunch of blocks saved to execute later. And your $user_tokens has not been initialized yet.

What I'd suggest is to use `initialize_my_stuff` inside your specs like this:

```
initialize_my_stuff.each do |user,token|
  describe 'foo bar' do
    ...
  end
end
```

Or, if it's super expensive, memorize it:

```
def user_tokens
  @user_tokens ||= initialize_my_stuff
end
```

and use it

```
user_tokens.each do |user,token|
  describe 'foo bar' do
    ...
  end
end
```